# Google Guice Named vs Annotation

Tags: java, dependency-injection, guice

I was going through Google Guice documentation and read about [UntargettedBinding](https://github.com/google/guice/wiki/UntargettedBindings). Basically there are two options

1. @Named
2. Binding annotation

My question is, which one is better?

With `@Named` I dont have to create boiler plates to use `annotations` but it comes at cost of less type safety. Annotation code looks more cleaner IMHO.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You specified the Pros and Cons of binding annotation in general as explained [here](https://github.com/google/guice/wiki/BindingAnnotations).
Your statements are correct.

One more advantage of @Named is to bind for properties using Names.bindProperties.
Where using binding annotation is irrelevant.
See [how to load properties](https://github.com/google/guice/wiki/FrequentlyAskedQuestions)

For **UntargetBinding** *(which sound like it was the actual question)* the documentation states two options

If you don't want to use binding annotation/@Named just declare the bind to the concrete class.
E.g.

```
bind(MyConcreteClass.class);
bind(AnotherConcreteClass.class).in(Singleton.class);
```

You **need** to use binding annotation/@Named you **must** still add the target binding i.e. the "**.toSometing**" methods (to, toProvider, toContractor etc.)

For example:

```
public class TestUntargetBinding {

    @Test
    void testTargetBindingViaImplementBy() {
        final var injector = Guice.createInjector(new AbstractModule() {
            @Override
            public void configure() {
                bind(MyConcreteClass.class)
                        .annotatedWith(Names.named("100"))
                        .toProvider(() -> new MyConcreteClass(100));
                bind(MyConcreteClass.class)
                        .annotatedWith(Names.named("200"))
                        .toProvider(() -> new MyConcreteClass(200));

            }
        });
        //imagine a class with a constructor
        // @Inject
        // SomeClass(@Named("100) MyConcreteClass myConcreteClass1){...}
        final var myConcreteClass1 = injector.getInstance(Key.get(MyConcreteClass.class, Names.named("100")));
        final var myConcreteClass2 = injector.getInstance(Key.get(MyConcreteClass.class, Names.named("200")));

        assertThat(myConcreteClass1.doSomething(), Is.is(100));
        assertThat(myConcreteClass2.doSomething(), Is.is(200));

    }

    static class MyConcreteClass {
        private int i;

        public MyConcreteClass(int i) {
            this.i = i;
        }

        public int doSomething() {
            return i;
        }
    }
}
```

Guice will not know witch class to bind the name/annotation to unless you will specify the "**toProvider**"

Comment: Guice link mentioned that ```Since the compiler can't check the string, we recommend using @Named sparingly. Defining your own purpose-built annotations provides better type-safety.``` Can someone explain what kind of type safety it is talking about?